# Trouble Send a specific value in a POST form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've a problem with a value that i have to send through a form, looks like the page doesn't receive the $sender value.

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> $("button[name='Security']").click(function(){
                          $("#placeholder").html(<?php $sender=basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>
                          "
            <form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='changePassword.php'>
            <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='username' class='col-sm-9 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-danger'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Change Password </span> </label>
        </div> <!-- col-sm-9 --> <!-- form-group -->  
        <div class='form-group'>
        <label style='margin:5px' for='currentpassword' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-info'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Current Password </span></label> 
        <input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='currentpassword' class='form-control' type='password' >
        </div> 
        <div class='form-group'>
        <label style='margin:5px' for='password' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-success'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> New Password </span></label> 
        <input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='password' class='form-control' type='password' >
        </div> 
        <div class='form-group'>
        <label style='margin:5px' for='confirmpassword' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-success'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Confirm Password </span></label> 
        <input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='confirmpassword' class='form-control' type='password' >
        </div> 
        <div class='form-group>
        <input type='hidden' name='sender' value=' <?php echo $sender; ?>' class='form-control' id='sender' > 
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='fa fa-check'></span> Change Password!</button> </div> </form>");
                                                          }); 
                      </script>
```

Actually i've troubles with the latest , i've tried in a lot of ways, also by place the assignment of the variable into the `value''`, but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Please change code like this

```
<?php
$sender = isset($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])? "":basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); 
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $("document").ready(function(){

                $("button[name=Security]").click(function(){
                                 $("#placeholder").html("<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='changePassword.php'><div class='form-group'><label for='username' class='col-sm-9 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-danger'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Change Password </span> </label></div> <!-- col-sm-9 --> <!-- form-group -->  <div class='form-group'><label style='margin:5px' for='currentpassword' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-info'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Current Password </span></label> <input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='currentpassword' class='form-control' type='password' ></div><div class='form-group'><label style='margin:5px' for='password' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-success'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> New Password </span></label><input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='password' class='form-control' type='password' ></div><div class='form-group'><label style='margin:5px' for='confirmpassword' class='col-sm-4 text-center' control-label><span class='label label-success'><i class='fa fa-eye'></i> Confirm Password </span></label><input style='margin:5px' class='col-sm-5' name='confirmpassword' class='form-control' type='password' ></div><div class='form-group><input type='hidden' name='sender' value=' <?php echo $sender; ?>' class='form-control' id='sender' ><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-block'><span class='fa fa-check'></span> Change Password!</button> </div> </form>");
                      }); 

            });


                      </script>
```

Comment: I have already wrote the code into the js like that, i just expand the code here in a way you can read it. I'll try this one cheers

Answer (score 0):

Actually i see i forgotten a `'` `<div class='form-group>`